# OnNmeaMessageListener not working for samsung j7, android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-gps

When testing an app that uses the OnNmeaMessageListener on a Samsung J7 the app breaks with this error

[image]

And I really don't get what is the problem, I've tested on other devices and the app works.

Code that I'm testing:

```
 LM.addNmeaListener(new OnNmeaMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNmeaMessage(String nmea, long timestamp) {
                 // do stuff
                } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a possible solution for SDK versions below 24

```
             if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                GpsStatus.NmeaListener nmeaListenerDeprecated = new GpsStatus.NmeaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
                        processNmeaData(nmea, timestamp);
                    }
                };
                try {
                    //noinspection JavaReflectionMemberAccess
                    Method addNmeaListener =
                            LocationManager.class.getMethod("addNmeaListener", GpsStatus.NmeaListener.class);
                    addNmeaListener.invoke(LM, nmeaListenerDeprecated);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    // TODO
                }
            } else {
                LM.addNmeaListener(new OnNmeaMessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNmeaMessage(String nmea, long timestamp) {
                        processNmeaData(nmea, timestamp);
                    }
                });
            }
```

with that solution I manged to get NMEA working for new and older devices.